# How to show the time as lower case am/pm

Tags: c#, wpf

I am display the start time - they would like the AM /PM to be in lower case. In this code, it is UPPER CASE. How to make this lower?

```
start = reh.START_DATE.Date;
start = start.AddHours(reh.START_TIME.Hour);
start = start.AddMinutes(reh.START_TIME.Minute);
```

Comment: ok but that will mean just the 'am/pm' part? not the actual date ?

Comment: You have to explain what you want the date format to be when turning it into a string if @SLaks suggestion doesn't suffice... See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx.

Comment: we currently have this:  01/01/01 8:00AM, we would like 01/01/01 8:00am

Comment: So then use start.ToString().ToLower() as answered by @gpmurthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider converting it to string and calling the ToLower() method...

e.g...

> string time = start.ToString().ToLower();

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the AM/PM and not the date to be lowercase then you could use

```
string date = string.Format("{0} {1}", start.Date, start.ToString("hh:mm tt").ToLower());
```